Please explain the purpose of R3 and R4 in this ground isolating amplifier
This schematic can be found here on page 15:

Here's what I do understand (I think):

The ground noise is common mode voltage, and the amplifier has high CMRR, so it gets rid of the ground noise at G2
R1 and R2 just make the amplifier unity gain

I am not able to explain what R3 and R4 do. Can anyone explain what R3 and R4 do?


Please explain the purpose of R3 and R4 in this ground isolating
amplifier

It boils down to recognizing that a differential amplifier using an op-amp has to use R3 and R4 (with the correct values) to fully reject common-mode noise on the sensed voltage source (\$V_{IN}\$). It's basically op-amp 101 stuff and, there are absolutely tons of references on google for this type of circuit.
Look up "differential amplifier using an op-amp".
